# SQL query to search latest occurrences based on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's suppose we have the following table:

```sql
col1                   col2                    col3  
---------------------------------------------------------
002478                 ABC                 2019-08-23    *
002478                 ABC                 2019-05-14    
002588                 CVMG                2019-01-07    *
002588                 IP                  2019-01-31    *
002588                 MMG                 2019-09-04    *
002588                 MMG                 2019-08-28    
002588                 NUSA                2019-11-04    *
002588                 NUSA                2019-04-24    
002746                 IE                  2019-01-15    *
003467                 IE                  2020-01-10    
003467                 IE                  2020-03-13    *
```

I wonder how to be able to get the latest occurences based on `col1` and `col2`.

---

Example:

```sql
col1                   col2                    col3  
---------------------------------------------------------
  ...                  ...                      ...
002746                 IE                  2019-01-15    *
003467                 IE                  2020-01-10    
003467                 IE                  2020-03-13    *
```

There I have 3 occurrences of IE on `col2` and 2 different numbers on `col1`. As result, we will have the latest IE 2746 and the latest IE 3467.

How can we get the latest `col3` value based on both `col1` and `col2`?

---

PS: I managed to do based on just 1 column, I already can get latest `col2` for example, but I doesn't have any idea how to implement the `col1` then.

PS²: All occurrences that are needed are marked with `*`.

---

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.col1, t.col2 order by t.col3 desc) rn
  from tablename t 
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, i'll see how that function works by myself but thanks for showing it. Didn't knew it exist!

Answer (score 2):

Use `DENSE_RANK()` window function to get multiple rows of latest occurrence. And also you can get Nth latest record by passing `rn` value to `where` clause.

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from (
  select t.*, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by t.col1, t.col2 order by t.col3 desc) rn
  from tablename t 
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: As per our need, Use ROW_NUMBER() , RANK(), DENSE_RANK() and some other window function.

Comment: Is there any way to do this query without window function? Just curious :)

Comment: It will take number of query lines. It’s difficult to do comparing pre-defined function.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
input(col1,col2,col3) AS (
          SELECT '002478','ABC', '2019-08-23'
UNION ALL SELECT '002478','ABC', '2019-05-14'
UNION ALL SELECT '002588','CVMG', '2019-01-07'
UNION ALL SELECT '002588','IP', '2019-01-31'
UNION ALL SELECT '002588','MMG', '2019-09-04'
UNION ALL SELECT '002588','MMG', '2019-08-28'
UNION ALL SELECT '002588','NUSA', '2019-11-04'
UNION ALL SELECT '002588','NUSA', '2019-04-24'
UNION ALL SELECT '002746','IE', '2019-01-15'
UNION ALL SELECT '003467','IE', '2020-01-10'
UNION ALL SELECT '003467','IE', '2020-03-13'
)
SELECT
  col1
, col2
, MAX(col3) AS col3
FROM input
GROUP BY
  col1
, col2
-- out    col1 | col2 |    col3    
-- out --------+------+------------
-- out  002588 | IP   | 2019-01-31
-- out  002588 | CVMG | 2019-01-07
-- out  002588 | MMG  | 2019-09-04
-- out  003467 | IE   | 2020-03-13
-- out  002478 | ABC  | 2019-08-23
-- out  002746 | IE   | 2019-01-15
-- out  002588 | NUSA | 2019-11-04
```